Why is my range-pattern not working as expected?
I have the following markdown file and vim script:

Example markdown file:
---
title: Humanure life cartoon 
date: 2024-12-13 
---

:::{#images}
<figure>[![humanure-life-cartoon-1.jpg](humanure-life-cartoon-1.jpg){width=600px}](humanure-life-cartoon-1.jpg)<figcaption>humanure-life-cartoon-1.jpg</figcaption></figure>
<figure>[![humanure-life-cartoon-2.jpg](humanure-life-cartoon-2.jpg){width=600px}](humanure-life-cartoon-2.jpg)<figcaption>humanure-life-cartoon-2.jpg</figcaption></figure>
:::
:::{#prompt}
:::

<style>
html {
    background: #090707;

[...]


Script:
func! GetImagePath() abort
    norm! /\%.lfigcap^M
    norm! f>
    norm! l
    norm! v/<^Mh
    norm! "wy
endfunc

func! GetComment()
    let @z = system("exiftool -Comment -s3 " . getreg('w') . " 2>/dev/null")
endfunc

/^:::{#image/,/^:::/g/<figcap/ exe "call GetImagePath()|norm f<i<br /><span class='comment'>" | call GetComment() | exe "norm a" . getreg('z') . "</span>"


The results of sourcing the script is inconsistent. I don't understand why sometimes it works and sometimes I get an error:

Pattern not found: <figcap

Any ideas what's going on here?

@Friedrich: You seem to 'be in charge'. Maybe I could delete everything in my post that makes my problem so 'mysterious'? It would certainly make me appear less stupid.

Do you still have something open in your question? How can we help you further? Otherwise maybe could you accept one of the solution using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons. It allow the question to rest :-)

If you have an answer to your question, then you should post it as an answer and accept it, not edit it into your question.

I'm not at all "in charge". I just make myself sound important. You can [edit] your question to improve it, clarify it, remove superfluous or misleading information. This is encouraged as explained in help.

@Vivian: I thought I did select an answer, your answer, when I clicked the ^ button below.

@romainl: I thought it might be helpful clarifying  the answer in terms I and perhaps others might make sense of. ;) I do see however that >>vivian is still refining his/her answer.

It does the opposite of clarifying things and you haven't selected Vivian's answer or even upvoted it.

@Tom, it seems you have not accept the answer yet :-). To accept the answer you have to use the v button and turn it green. You can also vote for the answer using the arrow button above the answer score number. But if you have the answer to your question the more important is to accept an answer such that the question can rest ;-)

Talking about accepting answers, it seems you have only accepted answers to at most a third of the questions you ever asked on this site. In one case, you answered yourself and didn't accept it. Accepting answers (if they do what you asked for) is an important part of how this site works. Even more importantly, questions without an accepted answer are bumped again and again to drive people mad. Please review your questions and accept those answers that worked for you.

@ramainl: Sorry I clicked what I now know to be up-vote button thinking this 'answered' the question; and it did say, "1 Answer" next to it. :-) As for my re-phrasing the answer, I don't see what harm there is in that. By that stage Vivian's answer - though I'm grateful to have it - was not as clear as it is now and I thought I'd do anyone else visiting the page a favour by putting it more layman's terms, so to speak.

@Friedrich: I see my error and will review previous questions.

I’ve taken the liberty of removing @Tom ‘s answer from the question, which I encourage them to repost as an answer (Tom: you can grab your old text by reviewing the edit history, which is available by clicking the clock with the rewind arrow under the voting buttons).

The problem is with the , range: /^:::{#image/,/^:::/
I would propose to use a ; range: /^:::{#image/;/^:::/
, range vs. ; range
In a , range Vim uses the current starting line to evaluate both locator expressions (start and end)
Both locators are relative to the cursor line.
In a ; range Vim uses:

the current starting line to evaluate the start locator expression and uses
the result of the start locator expression as a starting point to evaluate the end locator expression.

The start locator is relative to the cursor line. The end locator is relative to the start locator.
Your example
01 ---
02 title: Humanure life cartoon 
03 date: 2024-12-13 
04 ---
05 
06 :::{#images}
07 <figure>[![humanure-life-cartoon-1.jpg](humanure-life-cartoon-1.jpg){width=600px}](humanure-life-cartoon-1.jpg)<figcaption>humanure-life-cartoon-1.jpg</figcaption></figure>
08 <figure>[![humanure-life-cartoon-2.jpg](humanure-life-cartoon-2.jpg){width=600px}](humanure-life-cartoon-2.jpg)<figcaption>humanure-life-cartoon-2.jpg</figcaption></figure>
09 :::
10 :::{#prompt}
11 :::
12 
13 <style>
14 html {
15     background: #090707;

, range
If the cursor is at the start of the buffer:

/^:::{#image/ corresponds to line 6
/^:::/ corresponds to line 6

that interval doesn't include <figcap hence the error?
If the cursor is between line 6 and line 8:

/^:::{#image/ corresponds to line 6 (if wrapscan is set)
/^:::/ corresponds to line 9

and everything goes fine.
; range
If wrapscan is set:

/^:::{#image/ correspond to line 6
/^:::/ corresponds to line 9

More information with :help :range-pattern

I'm confused: I thought :/pattern/,/pattern/ delimited the block over which subsequent commands were run. Vim would start at the top of the buffer and look for the first pattern; then continue through the file until finding the second pattern. It seems it's dependent on the position of the cursor when the command is run? How does ^:::{#image match ^:::?

The error is with then continue it is instead searching the second pattern from the same starting position hence in your case the two lines (start and end) are the same.

Maybe more simple is /^:::{#image/,/^:::$/g/<figcap/ exe [...]

This will indeed also work in your case when the cursor is in the first line (or before  :::{#image) and the ::: is not used for another structure before :::{#image. It still believe the ; fits better the markdown semantic in general :-)
